# GQL error from Cloud Datastore Viewer for string-encoded key

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get entity from Google DataStore using Admin Console.
I use `SELECT * FROM User where __key__ = KEY('ag9wYWdhbGd1eS1zdGF0aWNyHAsSBUNhY2hlIhEvYnV0dG9ucy9lZGl0LmdpZgw')`.
In accordance with GQL docs it should work

> KEY('encoded key')

OR

> KEY('kind','name'/ID [, 'kind', 'name'/ID...])

but I'm getting

```
GQL query error ... Encountered "\'ag9wYWdhbGd1eS1zdGF0aWNyHAsSBUNhY2hlIhEvYnV0dG9ucy9lZGl0LmdpZgw\'" at line 1, column 40. 
Was expecting one of: <UNQUOTED_NAME> ... <QUOTED_NAME> ...
```

But the request `SELECT * FROM User where __key__ = KEY(User, 5126463837700096)` works fine.

How can I get the entity using string-encoded key?

Comment: Have you checked that it is a valid encoded key ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the valid one. Anyway I think it should return the empty row but not the error.

Comment: What throws me is the error.  Specifically Encountered "\'a it's escaping the quote character with \.  Are you sure the 'quote character your using is valid ?

Comment: Yes. I tried double quotes, copied quote character, etc...

Comment: It seems that the parser  always expect 2 \ 4 \ 6 parameters for the KEY function and the first one must be without quotes.  So the KEY function in console doesn't work with string-encoded key now.  It is shame that I cannot find in the console an entity by string-encoded key that used as reference from another entity.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. just checked in my datastore viewer

Comment: If by "Google Datastore" you mean *Cloud* Datastore (rather than the datastore of app engine), there are GQL syntax differences, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference .

Comment: @AlexMartelli thank you! The documentation for Cloud Datastore GQL is the relevant. As I can see in there is no way to get KEY from string-encoded key in Cloud Datastore  GQL.

Comment: @PavelBunygin, unfortunately I think you're right -- please accept your own answer to mark this Q as closed, *and* if you think it would be a good idea (I personally would!) file a feature request on the public issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list to help us possibly schedule such a feature for future delivery -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore GQL doesn't support getting KEY from string-encoded key.